# Best solution for Swift Foursquare API

Tags: ios, swift, foursquare, alamofire, swifty-json

I am looking to integrate Foursquare with a project for iOS using Swift. Would it be a wiser solution to use [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#integration) with the Foursquare API or to use the [das-quadrant](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/das-quadrat) API. I ask because I find very little information regarding Foursquare API. To add to the question i am using Swift2.0 would it be better to just use bare swift?

Also can i ask why SwiftyJson makes mention of wrapping another API called AlamoFire. Both APIs seem to perform the same task?

Comment: SwiftyJSON parse JSON, while AlamoFire does the network fetching. I don't recommend parsing JSON using pure Swift unless you have lots of experience with string manipulation and even more time.

Comment: Hmm  not in Swift. If this is true I do not really need AlamoFire correct?

Comment: It seems that `das-quadrant` does the job of both `SwiftyJSON` and `AlamoFire`.  The only issue is these APIs are written in Swift 1.2 which is not compatible with 2.0, so it would take some work to get it working.

Comment: Hmm yes it does seem to cause issue when I open it with xcode 7. SwiftyJson opens right away. In your opinion would it be better to just use das-quadrant since it was on foursquares page or would it be better to just figure it out with SwiftyJson? Again would i really need AlamoFire, I seem to be able to get what I need using classes in Foundation(from UIKit) import

Comment: To me it seems that using Das Quadrat would be easier because it handles the networking and the JSON. The issue is migrating it to Swift 2, which can be mostly done in Xcode using the built-in tool, but there may still be some issues you must resolve manually.